# matlab: return 2 numbers after decimal points in a matrix column

Tags: matlab, precision

Sorry if this is stupid question, but I'm new to MATLAB. I have a big matrix which contains `float` numbers and I want to change matrix to show two numbers after the decimal point.

When I enter below code in the command window:

```
 sprintf('%.2f',  ObjectTrack3(5,6))
```

It's ok and the output is: `ans = 3.40`

However, when I add `sprintf('%.2f',  ObjectTrack3(i,6))` in my code to show only two numbers after decimal points of all of the items in column 6 from `ObjectTrack3`, it just gives me an error.

How can I do this?

(The code is for converting cell array to matrix)

with guide of somebody I just noticed that the actual number for one of the cells of matrix is 44.849998474121094 but I just see 44.8500 
0.400000005960465 is shown 0.4000

Why it adds zero ? why it does not show 0.4 and 44.85 ?

Comment: What is the type of `ObjectTrack3(i,6)`? Can you type `class(ObjectTrack3(i,6))` and tell the result?

Comment: What value did i have, was that in a loop? What about ObjectTrack(:,6)?

Comment: that's not work either ! here is the error ??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> convertLogFiles at 35
    ObjectTrack1(i,6) =  sprintf('%.2f',  ObjectTrack1(:,6));

Comment: @melisa Please type `datatipinfo(ObjectTrack1(i,6))` at the command prompt and tell us the result.

Comment: I add datatipinfo(ObjectTruck1(:,6)) and it gives me 1200 numbers , I copy paste some of them here : 0.4000
    0.4000
    0.4000
    0.4000
    0.4000
    0.4000
    0.4000
    0.4000
    0.4000
    0.5000
    0.5000
    0.5000
    0.5000
    0.5000
    0.6000
    0.6000
    0.6000
    0.5000
    0.5000
    0.5000
    0.5000
    0.5000

Comment: Your error message you're not typing `sprintf()`, but instead `ObjectTrack(i,6) = sprintf()`.  Big difference.  That's the error.  ObjectTrack holds doubles, sprintf produces a string.  You can't put a string into a double array.  What does you mean, by the way, about converting a cell array to a matrix?  What does that have to do with sprintf and display formats?

Comment: I\m new to matlab and I just searched how can I do this . do you know any other commands that I could use in my code and change matrix ?

Comment: Why do you want to change the matrix?  "Showing" the values with 2 decimal places is accomplished just with sprintf, and is related to the display.  You don't want to degrade your internal accuracy for computations for the benefit of the display.  Can you back up a little and tell us what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you were on the right track, you just had some problems with the syntax.
Assuming that `ObjectTrack` is a matrix, what you should do is the following:

```
sprintf('%.2f\n', ObjectTrack3(:, 6))
```

This selects the 6<sup>th</sup> column from `ObjectTrack3` and sends it to the `sprintf` command. Note that `sprintf` operates on each of the elements of its input column vector, hence the `'\n'` so that every element is printed in a new line.

**Edit:** This answer also assumes that you just want to *print* the column with a desired precision, but not change it. If you want the latter, consider Memming's answer.

Comment: @melisazand If you want to change the matrix, then Memming's answer suits you. Memming suggests rounding the values up to the 2nd digit after the decimal point. Nevertheless, MATLAB will still show trailing zeroes when you _print_ unless you tell it otherwise, for instance using `sprintf`.

Comment: sprintf and Memming's answer change all of the matrix to zero !

Comment: You must have done something wrong, because the code works. Consider the following example: `ObjectTrack3 = rand(6); ObjectTrack3 = round(ObjectTrack3 * 100) / 100;`. Then try `ObjectTrack3(:, 6)` and `sprintf('%.2f\n', ObjectTrack3(:, 6))`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments of @Peter, I think what you want is:

`ObjectTrack3 = round(ObjectTrack3 * 100) / 100;`

It should be intuitive enough to understand. `sprintf` is to create strings, not doubles.

Comment: -1: This will _round_ the values to 2 numbers after the decimal point, not _print_ them. Unless that's what the OP wants (in which case my downvote is undeserved and I will remove it).

Comment: Well, I will delete my answer if this is not what she wants. I guess she said "show", which means print, so I think you are right. :P
(But the again, on the title, she said return...so it's confusing)

Comment: Don't delete it just yet, I'm not so sure anymore what the OP wants either.

Comment: I want to change the matrix and I test all of this command . no one works in my code

Comment: @melisazand if the matrix is already of 2 decimal points precision that you want, why do you want to do any further processing? What do you mean by "show", exactly? Could you explain the desired output?

Comment: the matrix shows 4 numbers after decimal points right now and I want to change that to only 2 numbers . I want to change the matrix not show !

Comment: @melisazand the numbers in the matrix are stored as double precision representation. 0.2 and 0.200 and 0.20000000 are all the same number. Maybe this is your confusion?

Comment: @melisazand then you already have a solution, right? `ObjectTrack3 = int32(ObjectTrack3 * 100)` should do the trick.

Comment: no , I just notice that ObjectTrack1(i,6) = fprintf('%.2f', ObjectTrack1(i, 6)); change the 0.4000 to 4

Comment: @melisazand You're using `fprintf` wrong. It returns the number of bytes, not the new value, and is used for printing, not for computation. Instead, use the code as shown in the answers.